# No more data to read from socket IO Error: Software caused connection abort: socket write error Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, procedure

I try to generate sample data in Oracle for my application, therefore I created a procedure that inserts into 2 separate tables and run an other procedure after the inserts.

I have a student table that looks like:
[image]

and have a results table:
[image]

My what_is_my_personality procedure just calculating the personality based on student data and test answers. It is waiting for an id for input.

In my procedure I try to create a for loop that runs for example 5 times and insert 5 rows into students table and results table then execute my procedure and calculate the personality.
To insert rows with same id's and to call what_is procedure with the same id I am using my sequence that generates my id in student_dim table.

My procedure:

```
create or replace 
procedure generate_sample_data
as
  nextId NUMBER := 0;
begin
  FOR i IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
  SELECT seq1.nextval INTO nextId FROM dual;
  INSERT ALL 
  INTO student_dim
  (id,stu_id,dep_code,fac_code,password,stu_fname,stu_lname,gender,loc_code,age,gp_avg,personality)
  VALUES
  (nextId,dbms_random.string('U', 6),default,default,default,default,default,round(dbms_random.value(1,2)),default,round(dbms_random.value(10,80)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),NULL)
  INTO results
  (student_id,OPN1,OPN2,OPN3,OPN4,AGG1,AGG2,AGG3,AGG4,NEU1,NEU2,NEU3,NEU4,EXT1,EXT2,EXT3,EXT4,CSN1,CSN2,CSN3,CSN4)
  VALUES
  (nextId,round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)),round(dbms_random.value(0,5)))
  SELECT * FROM dual;
  what_is_my_personality(nextId);
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
end;
```

After It runs I got socket write error:
[image]

Some logging info:
[image]

My Oracle version: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2

Comment: It seems there is something going wrong with your development tool. This isn't a SQL or PL/SQL error.

Comment: Do you see something wrong in my code? Some people says this is a bad habbit to commit like this. I do not know how to write this with row generator. Btw I am using sqldeveloper.